# FluentValidation wrong response via MediatR pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I am using this `ValidationBehavior` class:

```
public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(
        TRequest request,
        RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)

    {
        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);

        var failures = _validators
            .ToAsyncEnumerable()
            .SelectAwait(async validator => await validator.ValidateAsync(context))
            .ToEnumerable()
            .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
            .Where(failure => failure is not null)
            .ToList();

        if (failures.Any())
        {
            throw new ValidationException(failures);
        }

        return await next();
    }
}
```

I am doing it via MediatR pipeline just like so:

```
        services.AddMediatR(options =>
        {
            options.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(ServiceCollectionExtension).Assembly);
            options.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));
        });
```

Validator is very simple, just checks if the amount is greater than 0.

```
internal class DepositCommandHandlerValidator : AbstractValidator<DepositCommand>
{
    public DepositCommandHandlerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.Amount).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Amount must be greater than 0.");
    }
}
```

And in controller there's an action:

```
    [HttpPatch("deposit")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Deposit([FromRoute] Guid id, [FromBody] decimal amount)
    {
        bool result = await _mediator.Send(new DepositCommand(id, amount), CancellationToken.None);
        if (result)
        {
            return NoContent();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Now, normal api errors result in correct message, for example, I send a completely empty body, I get:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-55b083e06040a567d23741ac86df0166-6c9093c560f5addc-00"
}
```

However, when it's a Validation Exception, I can see the correct message and that's ok, but also I can see the whole stacktrace. For example, let's say I enter a negative value inside request body, I get:

```
FluentValidation.ValidationException: Validation failed: 
 -- Amount: Amount must be greater than 0. Severity: Error
   at BankApp.Core.Middleware.ValidationBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\Jan\source\repos\BankApi\BankApi.Core\Middleware\ValidationBehavior.cs:line 33
   at BankApp.Api.Controllers.CustomersController.Deposit(Guid id, Decimal amount) in C:\Users\Jan\source\repos\BankApi\BankApi.Api\Controllers\CustomersController.cs:line 25
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:7098
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.33.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2
Postman-Token: 72d7805a-490a-478c-a1d1-a5d53283f05e
```

Why is it sending the whole stacktrace?

Comment: The reason is you are throwing an exception but you don't have any middleware that handles the exception or converts it to any response code with some payload.

Answer (score 0):

Error was in the middleware. It didn't handle the exception correctly just as in the comment